# How to split a string at the first space

Tags: c, string, split

I have a string of numbers like this:
 160 01 11 12 33 44 44 ...
and I want to split from the start until the first space like this:
160 | 01 11 12 33 44 44....
For example I could put the string before first space in a array and the string after in other array so.

arr1[]='160'

arr2[]='01 11 12 33 44 44...'

I'm extracting this type of string from a file so my code is this:

```
int le_ficheiro(char* filename) {
FILE *ficheiro=fopen(filename,"r");
size_t len=0;
char *line=NULL;
ssize_t read;
if(ficheiro==NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}



while((read = getline (&line, &len,ficheiro))!=-1)   //read line by line
{
    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n",read);
    printf("%s\n",line);
    printf("Aqui : %c\n",line[0]);

}
fclose(ficheiro);
if(line)
    free(line);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

I need some help to how do I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtok` to split your string. Here is the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok).

In this specific case, it is enough to find the first space and split.

```
char *s1;
char *s2;
char *sp;

sp = strchr(line, ' ');
if (!sp) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

s1 = strndup(line, sp-line); /* Copy chars until space */
s2 = sp+1; /* Skip the space */

...

free(s1);
```

Comment: and it splits just in the first space?

Answer (score 0):

```
const char* str;
char first[5] ,rest[50]; 
sscanf(str, "%d %s", first,rest);
int first_i = atoi(first);
```

**or**

```
double first_d = atof(first);
```

this should work too.